# Define Attribute Content Programmatically

Tags: c#

I am writing a program which will connect to a I2C to USB controller. I am using WPF.
 I decided to create a Device class to contain the hardware description and all its attributes so I can use them to display properties and have the end user modify the settings of the hardware.
 I have most of the above working, except 2 attributes.
 Most attributes are strings or int or byte, etc... so they are easy to work with, like the example below:

```
private string _name;
[Category("General")]
[ReadOnly(false)]
[DisplayName("Module Name")]
[Description("Enter descriptive string ")]
public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Module Name"); } }
```

The 2 attributes I am having a hard time with need to have a list to populate.
So I read the hardware setting, and it returns that it supports I2C, SPI, and UART.
Now I want to be able to pass those to the "CommunicationType" attribute, and have it display as a list in the properties window.
To see if my program is working, I created the following class:

```
public class CommunicationType : IItemsSource
{
    public ItemCollection GetValues()
    {
        ItemCollection sizes = new ItemCollection();
        sizes.Add((int)PP_COM_Wrapper.enumInterfaces.I2C, "I2C");
        sizes.Add((int)PP_COM_Wrapper.enumInterfaces.ISSP, "ISSP");
        sizes.Add((int)PP_COM_Wrapper.enumInterfaces.JTAG, "JTAG");
        sizes.Add((int)PP_COM_Wrapper.enumInterfaces.SPI, "SPI");
        sizes.Add((int)PP_COM_Wrapper.enumInterfaces.SWD, "SWD");
        sizes.Add((int)PP_COM_Wrapper.enumInterfaces.SWD_SWV, "SWD SWV");
        return sizes;
    }
}
```

Then in the attribute, I have the following:

```
private int _comtype;
[Category("Settings")]
[ReadOnly(false)]
[ItemsSource(typeof(CommunicationType))]
[DisplayName("Communication Type")]
public int CommunicationType { get { return _comtype; } set { _comtype = value; OnPropertyChanged("Communication Type"); } }
```

So when I run it, it gives the user the possibility to select from a drop down, one of the communication types.
Now the question is, how do I populate it programmatically? Some of the hardware only supports I2C and SPI, so I only want to populate the list with 2 items based on the hardware.